# application crash due to navigate to different views

Tags: iphone, ios

My application crashes when I navigate to different view for more than 10 to 11 times. I mean I have 6 buttons on main screen which on pressing bring you to different views. when I press these buttons repeatedly then my app crashes. I have spent 3 days but comes up with no solution. here is the code where app crashes

when i uncomment release statement then it crashes after first time.

```
-(IBAction) goToLiveAlerts{
    teamAlerts *showLiveAlerts=[[teamAlerts alloc] initWithNibName:@"teamAlerts" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:showLiveAlerts animated:YES];
        //[showLiveAlerts release];
}
```

when i uncomment then i console error is
"wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
[Switching to process 2093]
[Switching to process 2093]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."
    -(IBAction)goToPhotos{
        picturesGallery *showPictures=[[picturesGallery alloc] initWithNibName:@"picturesGallery" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:showPictures animated:YES];
            //[showPictures release];
    }

Comment: Provide the code and crash backtrace please. We're not telepathic.

Comment: Have you profile your app and see whether the views not in focus are deallocated?

Comment: how to deallocate the views which are not in focus. kindly provide example. It will help me to understand

Comment: You will be required to release the objects while viewDidDisappear method. This kind of error comes off when memory is not managed properly. You are creating the objects but they are not released at the appropriate instant.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written. Are you using ARC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use ARC or not? If not, according to your code, there is some memory leaks in your code, try this:

```
-(IBAction)goToPhotos{
    picturesGallery *showPictures=[[picturesGallery alloc] initWithNibName:@"picturesGallery" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:showPictures animated:YES];
    [showPictures release];
}
```

Anyway, you need to provide more code crash log.

---

According to your crash log, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means there is some memory leaks. Enable `NSZombie` in Xcode to debug. In Xcode 4.3, go to `Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics` and check `Enable Zombie Objects`.

Comment: and if i use release statement then it crashes after navigating 5 times

Comment: ARC is [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), with ARC enabled, you don't need to release `showPictures`, as compile will do it for you. Without ARC, you must release `showPictures` manually.

Comment: Provide more crash log please.

Comment: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
[Switching to process 2093]
[Switching to process 2093]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means there is some memory leaks. Enable `NSZombie` in Xcode to debug. In Xcode 4.3, go to `Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics` and check `Enable Zombie Objects`.